# Get product or page name inside the parent template?

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm integrating a custom html inside Magento and in the layout I have the h1 (title) before the main container. So, I need to get every every title in the 1column.phtml template page. How to get the product data or a CMS page title from the page 1column.phtml or 2columns-right.phtml for example?

I tried to do the following:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product') : ?>
<h1 id="titulo" class="container"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...and I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Just need use register variable `$_product=Mage::registy('current_product')` for getting product object

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product') :
$_product=Mage::registy('current_product'); 
?>
<h1 id="titulo" class="container"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is not create no  issue

Comment: It worked now. I just put $_product->getName(). How to get the title for a CMS page or another page like checkout or my account etc. ?

Comment: On cms & Other page you need product object by mage:getmodrl

Comment: Ok, I will search about how to use it. Thanks for now!